# Sqlserver query to retrieve from child table

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have the following example table structure. Want to retrieve customer who didnt have notificationtypeid = 2 ie who have never been sent a reminder email.
Can anyone help me how to write the sql query for this?

```
CustomerNotification:
-------------------
CustomerId      Notificationtypeid
8201                1
8201                2
8202                1
8203                1
10209               1


Customer:
--------
CustomerId
8201
8202
8203
10209

NotificationType:
----------------
Notificationtypeid  Name
1                   Invite email
2                   Reminder
```

i tried the following but not working as i am sure this not how it should be written :

```
  select cd.customerId
  tn.notificationtypeid from Customer cd
  inner join CustomerNotification tn
  on cd.customerid= tn.customerid
  where cd.customerid not in( select customrid from customnotification where notificationtypeid=2
```

)
      order by cd.customerid

Expected Result:

```
CustomerId      Notificationtypeid
8202                1
8203                1
10209               1
```

But using my query i get:

```
CustomerId      Notificationtypeid
8201                1                    <-- I dont want this in result
8202                1
8203                1
10209               1
```

Comment: What does *"not working"* mean?

Comment: Have updated my question. Hope you got it what i meant by "not working"? Thanks

Comment: If `Notificationtypeid` has a value of `'1*` that query will never run. `tn.notificationtypeid not in (2)` will return an error along the lines of "Unable to convert '1*" to datatype int". You'll need to use `NOT IN ('2')`.

Comment: its not 1*, i have just highlighted that record to show that i dont want this record. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cd.customerId
  tn.notificationtypeid from Customer cd
  inner join CustomerNotification tn
  on cd.customerid= tn.customerid
  where cd.customerid not in( select customrid from customnotification where notificationtypeid=2)
```

This query solved my issue. Let me know if there is better way.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this SQL Server query to get desired output:-

```
select CustomerId, Notificationtypeid from CustomerNotification
  where Notificationtypeid =1
```